# Function Pointers and Access - Why is this code legal?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, private-members

I came across something which surprised me quite recently and it'd be nice to have some clarification on it.

Say I have a class `A` which is comprised of the following:

```
#include "B.h"

class A {

private:
    B* inst_b;
    std::mt19937 mt_eng; 

    static void update_routine(double& _p, std::mt19937& _eng) {
        // does stuff, not important here
    }

public:
    A() {
        std::random_device rd;
        mt_eng = std::mt19937(rd());
    }

    void updateP() {
        inst_b->update_quantity(update_routine, mt_eng);
    }

    //...
};
```

and a class `B` which is as follows:

```
#include <random>

class B {

protected:
    double qty; 
    //...
public:
    B() {
        qty = 0.0;
    }

    void update_quantity(void(*fptr)(double&, std::mt19937&), std::mt19937& _eng) {
        fptr(qty, _eng); // no error here
    }

    //...
};
```

Now I would've thought that the compiler would complain about trying to call the function in the body of `update_quantity` as `update_routine` of `A` is a `private` member function and therefore I'd think trying to call it from `B` would result in an `inaccessible method` error or something along those lines - even if it has been passed as a function pointer.

In my project when I do the above it compiles and executes successfully - why is this? Granted, it's quite useful for me that it indeed *does* compile and run but I'd like to understand why this is the case.

P.S: I apologise if this is a duplicate, please link the relevant topic if this is the case.

Comment: How is B::update_quantity trying to call A::update_routine?

Comment: `A` has access to its own `update_routine()`, so is able to provide a valid address.     When that pointer is passed to `B::update_quantity()`, the only information passed is its address and type (a function with specified set of arguments/types and return value).   That does not include information about accessibility - accessibility only applies to its name, and that information is not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class B {

protected:
    double qty; 
public:
    B() {
        qty = 0.0;
    }

    void update_quantity(void(*fptr)(double&, std::mt19937&), std::mt19937& _eng) {
        fptr(qty, _eng); // no error here
    }

};
```

There is no reference in the above code to the `A` class.
You are de-referencing the `fptr` in the
`update_quantity`function, but the prototype
for `fptr` doesn't have any references to the
`A` class-so there is no privilege violation from 
class B to A.

The address of `update_routine` might be passed in as a 
function pointer parameter- but the A function is still not directly encoded in the class of B, as written.  In other words, if the function pointer is a parameter only, then de-referencing this function pointer parameter does not necessarily cause a class privilege violation.

`fptr` is strictly local to `update_quantity` and is not considered part of the A class..

Answer (score 2):

The terms public and private (and protected) really only refer to the names of things -- it is the name `update_routine` that is private and can only be resolved to an actual function within the scope of the class.  Since you are only using the name within the scope of the class, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is passed from inside A, where it is quite visible. Visibility does not change function's type.
If you tried to call `A::update_routine` from `B::update_quantity`, this would be illegal. But A has given the address to B and delegated function call to it. Meanwhile B is agnostic of what function address it receives.